# Can I automate the creation of a query in Power Query in Office 2013

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013, powerquery

I'm leaning towards Power Query more and more now as an extraction and data-merging tool (in combination with VBA). This creates trouble in some instances since our enterprise is a mix of Office 2013 and 2016. I've designed a tool in 2016 that automates the deletion and creation of queries, but it doesn't work in 2013. My solution was to develop an alternative solution for 2013 users, but it appears that query creation can't be automated in this environment. Is this true?

I'm importing two Excel files into Power Query for filtering and field arrangement, then merging the two data sets to produce one table with everything I need. In 2016, I'm able to fully automate this process. I've tried a few techniques with the macro recorder in 2013 and have had no success capturing any of the query creation steps. The fact that PQ is an add-on to 2013 is probably the reason for this, but I'm curious if someone has discovered a work-around.

Upgrading everyone to 2016 is not an option.

I found this and I'm about to try it out:

https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/10/22/refresh-power-query-with-vba/

Comment: It is true that you cannot create or delete a query in Excel where PQ is installed as an Add-On. It's also not clear why you would need to do that here. You can refresh an output table that is linked to PQ from VBA, and you can use VBA to alter a Query indirectly by setting parameters that are loaded into PQ from the Excel workbook (look up "power query parameter table" for a number of ways to do this).

Comment: Ok I'll look that up, thanks.

Comment: The reason I delete/recreate is because I was getting random and intermittent errors when using VBA to refresh a query. I could never figure out the rhyme nor the reason. I discovered that completely removing the query and then recreating it solved this problem.

Comment: When refreshing queries from VBA it is often useful to disable the "Enable Background Refresh" option on the query (either from the UI or temporarily through VBA). This will cause Excel (and the VBA script) to pause until the query is finished refreshing, which is important if you are doing anything with the results of query in VBA.

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well back then and this did not prevent the error. The frustrating part was that it did not occur consistently. I'd run several successful tests and it would work for a few to several days and then out of nowhere the error would return. Since adopting the delete and recreate method, the error has not manifested.